# Retrieve data from callback function if this function is of return type

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
function getPageDetails(callback,filterlink) { 
        var message=1+2;
        callback(message,filterlink); 
    }); 
};

function test(message,filterlink)
{
    var data=message+1;
    return data
}

function test1(filterlink)
{
    var testdata=getPageDetails(test,filterlink)
    alert(testdata)
}
```

In this example, when I call test1(filterlist) method with a parameter and want to call a callback function. I did get any data in testdata variable. It should be 4 in alert. Can anyone help?

Comment: You need to return your callback: `return callback(a, b)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `getPageDetails` isn't returning anything.

While executing `callback(message, filterlink)` you need to return it's result so `var testdata` will get the value assigned :

```
function getPageDetails(callback, b) {
    [...]
    return callback(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make use of promise  , that will resolve your issue

```
let p1 = new Promise(
       (resolve, reject) => {
            log.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', thisPromiseCount +
                ') Promise started (<small>Async code started</small>)<br/>');
            // This is only an example to create asynchronism
            window.setTimeout(
                function() {
                    // We fulfill the promise !
                    resolve(thisPromiseCount);
                }, Math.random() * 2000 + 1000);
        }
    );

    // We define what to do when the promise is resolved with the then() call,
    // and what to do when the promise is rejected with the catch() call
    p1.then(
        // Log the fulfillment value
        function(val) {
            log.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', val +
                ') Promise fulfilled (<small>Async code terminated</small>)<br/>');
        })
    .catch(
        // Log the rejection reason
       (reason) => {
            console.log('Handle rejected promise ('+reason+') here.');
        });
```

Full info about : [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: The issue with his code is that he forgot to add a return statement to his function. Imho suggesting him a more complicated programming pattern as the solution to a problem of understanding functions and callbacks is not recommended.

Comment: @Delpes - i got his problem, but i suggest him better way to do it.....which is complicated but once understood good to user in future ..that is my goal

Comment: Can you please explain me how can i use it in my case...from where i can call my callback method and return a value from test function.please reply.

Comment: @anshul - in this part    p1.then(, ..............here you have to create promise of your first function which does message = 1+3; than in p1.then part you can do alert i.e. you call back function test

Answer (score 0):

If you return the callback like suggested in the comments and remove the `});` in the first function it works.
I highly reccomend you to use the solution of Pranay Rana as it is much better. It's worth to invest in the understanding of promises if you work with js!

```js
function getPageDetails(callback, filterlink) { 
  var message = 1 + 2;
  return callback(message, filterlink); 
}


function test(message, filterlink) {
 var data = message + filterlink;
  return data
}

function test1(filterlink) {
  var testdata = getPageDetails(test, filterlink)
  alert(testdata)
}

test1(1);
```